# Started stub server for project [] on port -1

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to create a single (fat) spring boot jar for consumer with producer's stub as a dependency to it. With this, when i start-up the consumer app, it should start the contract stub as well.

Here is what I have done so far:

I used this pom example (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_with_external_contracts/pom.xml#L98) and created a fat jar for producer

producer.pom

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <baseClassMappings>
                        <baseClassMapping>
                            <contractPackageRegex>.*contract.*</contractPackageRegex>
                        </baseClassMapping>
                    </baseClassMappings>
                    <contractDependency>
                        <groupId>com.groupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>producer</artifactId>
                    </contractDependency>
                    <contractsMode>LOCAL</contractsMode>
                    <classifier>stubs</classifier>
                    <basePackageForTests>com.groupId.producer</basePackageForTests>
                    <convertToYaml>true</convertToYaml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This is then imported into my consumer.pom like below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>producer</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

The application properties are as below: 
producer - application.properties
server.port=8081

consumer - application.properties

```
stubrunner.ids=com.groupId:producer:+:stubs:8081
stubrunner.stubsMode=LOCAL
stubrunner.repositoryRoot=com.groupId.producer
stubrunner.minPort=8081
```

ControllerTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@AutoConfigureStubRunner( ids = "com.groupId:producer:+:stubs:8081", 
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL ) 
@DirtiesContext
public class ContractTests extends AbstractTest {

... 
}
```

ConsumerApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableStubRunnerServer
@Slf4j
public class ConsumerApplication {
...
}
```

ContractService.java

```
public class ContractService {

public @ResponseBody MockResponse verifyWithContract(SomeObj someObj) {

        ResponseEntity<MockResponse> response = this.restTemplate.exchange(
                RequestEntity
                .post(URI.create( http://localhost:8081/someEndpoint ))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(someObj), MockResponse.class);

        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

I have 2 issues:

1. When I run my test I get the below exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.server.HttpStubsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Remote repositories for stubs are not specified and work offline flag wasn't passed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]

I have also tried the below in test but that didn't help:

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner( ids = "com.groupId:producer:+:stubs:8081", 
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE, rootRepository="com.groupId.producer" )
```

2. Ignoring the test failures, when i start the application, it starts fine with the below log lines

```
2019-04-09 11:38:50.454  INFO 75383 --- [           main] o.s.c.contract.stubrunner.StubServer     : Started stub server for project [com.groupId:producer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:stubs] on port -1
2019-04-09 11:38:50.454  INFO 75383 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor    : All stubs are now running RunningStubs [namesAndPorts={com.gorupId:producer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:stubs=-1}]
2019-04-09 11:38:50.673  INFO 75383 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https) with context path ''
```

but when i send a request to the rest URL: https://localhost:8080/someEndpoint 
it returns the below error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1554837050058,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "I/O error on POST request for \"http://localhost:8081/someEndpoint\": Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)",
    "path": "/someEndpoint"
}
```

log lines:

```
2019-04-09 12:10:50.045 ERROR 75383 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8081/someEndpoint": Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-contract-shade-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
```

I think i am missing some stubRunner configuration for stubrunner port.

Comment: From what i see you're basically mixing everything. Can you elaborate on what you want to exactly achieve?

Comment: @marcin-grzejszczak, I am trying to have my contracts as a standalone spring boot application. I need it to be able to receive json requests that are logged in a specific format, run it against the contract and return a async response..

Comment: Why not just use the default approach with stub runner boot? You can just fetch the stub runner boot fat jar and just run it

Comment: Do you have an example link to share? How will the post for contract work? Can the end point names be the same in restController and the contract or do they need to be different?

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#_stub_runner_boot_application

Comment: @marcin-grzejszczak, I do have atEnableStubRunnerServer in the fat jar application and the stub starts up but at port=-1.. The atAutowired StubFinder also finds the stub but at post -1, which is not helpful either.

Comment: Maybe you have only messaging contracts and that's why